# C# lambda expression, scoped variable value

Tags: c#, lambda, scope, closures, event-handling

hi I am trying to write an lambda for an event handler. so I can provide more information to the method that gets called.

so I am doing:

```
button.Click+=new EventHandler ((object sender, EventArgs args) => 
{ button_click (i, sender, args); });
```

where:

```
public void button_click (int i, object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
```

ok so this works as in the method get called, but `i` is always the last known value of `i`, I really want the value at the point where the lambda is pass to the event. How do you do that?

thanks

Comment: see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx to understand the reason why you have to copy the variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just create a copy of the variable:

```
int currentI = i;
button.Click+=new EventHandler ((object sender, EventArgs args) => 
    { button_click (currentI, sender, args); });
```

Note that you've got a certain amount of cruft there. You can write it more simply as:

```
int currentI = i;
button.Click += (sender, args) => button_click(currentI, sender, args);
```

Personally I'd rename the `button_click` method to conform with .NET naming conventions though.

Comment: thanks Jon that sussed it and I lost the extra curly braces too :D, although I do like to be explicit about variable types, as it helps self document code. BTW: what would you have called the method then? Thanks again

Comment: @651bobby: Given that it's a `Click` event, I'd assume that's sufficiently well-known that the types will be obvious. I'd name the method after what it *does* rather than what happens to call it. It's hard to know what that is from the code we've got though. If you really want it tied to the button click, I'd call it something like `HandleButtonClick`.

Comment: ok, thanks, I will do that from now on, but I will still stick with my explicit typing as a matter personal preference.